# Correlation in WF 4 on workflow InstanceId

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, correlation

In Windows Workflow Foundation under .NET 4.0, is there a way to correlate operations based on the InstanceId (GUID) of a long-running persisted workflow?

For example:

1. Operation 1 creates workflow instance, returns workflow instance ID to client
2. Client may later query InstanceStore database to retrieve InstanceId from Instances view
3. Client calls Operation 2 and passes InstanceId for content-based correlation

I can do all of this if I have the client create and pass a GUID to the first operation, use that value in content-based correlation, then promote that value when persisting. That seems redundant, though, since the workflow is already creating a GUID for the instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an activity to retrieve the workflow instance Id from the context passed in and return this from the SendReply activity. Next use the CorrelationInitializer on the SendReply to setup the request correlation.

Comment: Ah, you mean the CodeActivityContext passed to the Execute method of the CodeActivity. "Context" is an overloaded term in this, uh, context. ;)

Comment: Thanks - that worked. I had to send the GUID back as a parameter with SendReplyToReceive to configure the CorrelationInitializer, but I wanted to do that anyway.

Comment: Yes, either the CodeActivityContext or the NativeActivityContext depending on your choice of activity and context is indeed somewhat overloaded. And message correlation is always done on some part of a WCF message so you have to return the WorkflowInstanceId to caller. But then they need to know the value for future messages anyway.